# Perl regex to capture group and stop matching

Tags: perl

I need some help with this perl regular expression

```
s/.*?<\?lsmb if\s*?(\S*)\s*?\?>/$1/
```

in the code below parsing out some non-whitespace chars `[A-Z][a-z][0-9][_]` surrounded by any number of whitespace and the other chars. I have tried various Perl regular expressions which are all commented out in the program below.

My main problem I think is stopping matching at the end.

The code below runs 8 tests, and I am hoping to find something that passes all 8.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

my $count = 0;
my $t = 0;
#examples of things I need to match, match => catagory
my $self = {  'customerfax' => 'alpha',
             '_____' => 'Underscore',
             '000000' => 'numeric',
             'letter_reason_4' => 'alfa-numeric-underscore',
             'customerphone7' => 'alfa-numeric', 
             'customer_phone' => 'alfa-underscore',
           };
# must contain   <?lsmb 'varname from $self' ?> 
# may contain any amount of whitespace chars where one is depected
# will end with \n that is removed by chop below         
my $test1 = qq|<?lsmb if customerfax ?>  caacaacac\n|;
my $test2 = qq|<?lsmb if _____ ?> bbb\n|;
my $test3 = qq|<?lsmb if 000000 ?> cccc\n|;
my $test4 = qq|<?lsmb if letter_reason_4 ?><t \></'><><><>\n|;  # /
my $test5 = qq| <?lsmb if customerfax ?> |;
my $test6 = qq|<?lsmb if  customerphone7   ?> \<?lsmb ignore this >n|;
my $test7 = qq|<?lsmb if  customer_phone  ?>\n|;
my $test8 = qq| avcscc 34534534 <?lsmb if letter_reason_4 ?> 0xffff\n|;

strip_markup($test1);
strip_markup($test2);
strip_markup($test3);
strip_markup($test4);
strip_markup($test5);
strip_markup($test6);
strip_markup($test7);
strip_markup($test8);

if ($count == 8) { print "Passed All done\n";}
else { print "All done passed  $count out of 8 Try again \n"; }


sub strip_markup { 
    $_= shift;
    #print "strip_markup $_ \n";
    if (/<\?lsmb if /) {
        chop; # gets rid ot the new line
        #original
        #s/.*?<\?lsmb if (.+?) \?>/$1/;
        #What I have tried:
        #s/.*?<\?lsmb if(?:\s)*?(\S+?)(?:\s)*?\?>\b/$1/;
        s/.*?<\?lsmb if\s*?(\S*)\s*?\?>/$1/;
        #s/.*?<\?lsmb if\s*?([A-Za-z0-9_]*?)\s*?\?>/$1/;
        #s/.*?<\?lsmb if[\s]*?(\S*?)[\s]*?\?>/$1/;
        #s/.*?<\?lsmb if (\S*?) \?>/$1/;
        #s/.*?<\?lsmb if (\S+?) \?>/$1/;
        #s/.*?<\?lsmb if ([\S]+?)([\s]+?)\?>/$1/;
        #s/.*?<\?lsmb if[\s]+([\S]+)[\s]+\?>/$1/;
        #s/.*?<\?lsmb if\s*?([\S]*?)\s*?\?>/$1/;
        #s/.*?<\?lsmb if\s+?([\S]+?)[\s]+?\?>/$1/;
        #s/.*?<\?lsmb if ([\S]+?) \?>/$1/;
        #s/.*?<\?lsmb if\s*?([\S_]*?)\s*?\?>/$1/;
        #s/.*?<\?lsmb if\s*?([[a-zA-Z]|[\d]|[_]]*?)\s*?\?>/$1/;
        #s/.*?<\?lsmb if\s*?([a-zA-Z\d_]*?)\s*?\?>/$1/;
        #s/.*?<\?lsmb if\s*?([^[:space:]]+?)\s*?\?>/$1/;

        $t++;
        print "Test $t ";
        #look up the result as the hash key
        my $ok = $self->{$_};
        if ($ok) { 
                $count++;
                print "OK passed $ok,";
        }
        print qq|Test Value : '$_' \n|;
    }
}
```

Here are some of the Tests and what they should return:

- Test1 = `<?lsmb if customerfax ?>  caacaacac\n` should return `customerfax`
- Test2 = `<?lsmb if _____ ?> bbb\n` should return   `_____`
- Test8 =  `avcscc 34534534 <?lsmb if letter_reason_4 ?> 0xffff\n`
  should return `letter_reason_4`

Comment: Can you show an example of output that you need from an input string?  The explanation isn't clear, with "_parsing some chars ... and the other chars_"

Comment: Why are you using `chop` instead of `chomp`? Actually, why are you modifying a global variable (`$_`) inside a function?

Comment: zdim -> thank you for your reply I updated the post with sample input and output. melpomene

Comment: melpomene:Thank you for this thought, I wrote this test code to replicate a bug in a larger Perl module, I am not the author of the original nor am I able to change the original code other than to fix the bug.

Comment: Perhaps I am not understanding what "_the Tests ... should return_" -- you can capture what you show in the edit by `/<\?lsmb if (\w+)/`.  Is that all you need, to extract the `customerfax` or underscores or zeroes or `letter_reason_4` ... ?

Comment: @turtle  Btw, to have people notified of comments you need `@` in front of their username.  The owner of the post (question or answer) always gets notified, I used it here as an example.

Comment: Is this example XML? It looks a bit like it, but I can't quite tell.

Comment: I don't think it's XML. But I would like to know what it is. Also, do you really need `use diagnostics`? Do you read those? Don't keep it when you roll out your code, it's slowing down stuff a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding of your requirements is right, the needed phrase is extracted by simple

```
my ($match) = $string =~ /<\?lsmb \s+ if \s+ (\w+)/x
```

In the *list context* the *match operator* `m//` returns a list with matches. Even if it's just one, we need the *list context* – in the *scalar context* its behavior is different. The list context comes from assigning to a list from it, `my (...) =`. The `/x` *modifier* merely allows us to use spaces inside, for readability. See [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) for starters.

What may precede `<?` doesn't have to be specified, since the pattern matches anywhere in the string. The `\w` is for `[A-Za-z0-9_]` (see [perlrecharclass](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html)), what seems to match your examples and description. The `\S` is more permissive. Nothing is needed after `\w+`.

Also, there is no need to first test whether the pattern is there

```
sub strip_markup 
{
    my ($test_res) = $_[0] =~ /<\?lsmb if (\w+)/;

    if ($test_res) {
        # ...
    }

    return $test_res;         # return something!
}
```

There is no reason for the substitution so we use a match.

I understand that you are working with code you can't change, but would still like to comment

- No need to remove the newline here. But when you do that, use [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) and *not* [chop](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chop.html)
- The sub uses global variables. That can lead to bugs. Declare in small scope. Pass
- The sub modifies global variables. That often leads to bugs while there is rarely *need* for it
- Use arrays for repetitions of the same thing
- This can be organized differently, to separate work more clearly

---

For example

```
my @tests = (
    qq|<?lsmb if customerfax ?>  caacaacac\n|,
    # ...
);

my ($cnt, $t);

foreach my $test (@tests) 
{
    my $test_res = strip_markup($test);

    if (defined $test_res) {
        $t++;
        print "Test $t ";
        #look up the result as the hash key
        my $ok = $self->{$test_res};
        if ($ok) { 
                $count++;
                print "OK passed $ok,";
        }
        print qq|Test Value : '$_' \n|;
    }
    else { }  # report failure
}

sub strip_markup {
    my ($test_res) = $_[0] =~ /<\?lsmb \s+ if \s+ (\w+)/x;
    return $test_res;
}
```

The `defined` test of `$test_res` is to allow for falsey things (like `0` or `''`) to be valid results.

The reporting code can, and should be, in another subroutine.

Comment: Thank you \w works. I will try to refactor the original code to not use $_.

Comment: @turtle Nice, thank you for the update :) It's good, I have two remarks. (1) When you take the argument in the function, why call it same name as what the result will be called?  It's easy to make mistakes.  Call it, say, `my $test_string = shift;` and then `my ($test_res) = $test_string =~ /.../; return $test_res;`  (2) In `/.../x` that `x` is to allow us to use spaces inside, just for readability.  When you don't use extra spaces you don't need the `x` _modifier_ (as it's called).

Comment: @turtle I added a paragraph with comments right below the regex, at the beginning.